# Http request duration with PHP5/Apache2

Tags: apache, http

Is there a way to get reliable information from HTTP server about the duration of a HTTP request?

Scenario of interest:

An AJAX request with data payload is dispatched targeting PHP script using POST method:

```
//dispatch ajax request
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "timing.php",
  data: {
         "payload":"some long string or something",
         "currentTime": +new Date() //miliseconds on client
        },
  success: function(response) { console.log(response) },
  error: function() { console.log('something went banana...') },
  dataType: "text"
});
```

PHP script "timing.php" may say something like:

```
<?php
//in the meanwhile, on a quiet server...
$currentTime = microtime(true); //microseconds on server
//send headers as necessary, and then, the payload
echo $currentTime * 1000 - $_POST["currentTime"];
?>
```

What I wish to know is what time elapsed between the moment in which request got to the http server until the server invoked the PHP script. How long did it take to process (load) the input arguments of the POST request. Not the time it took from Javascript currentTime until PHP $currentTime, but the one Apache took to load the "payload" (and "currentTime") from the AJAX request.
Time should be gathered on the server side.

Whereabouts:

- Client and server are in the same timezone (also, client didn't do anything exciting with it's time settings),
- Server has PHP5/Apache2 with default configuration and modules,
- Desired time resolution is miliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, best bet to have somewhat reliable information with PHP environment is $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] variable, available since PHP 5.4.0. This will neglect some time needed to start the actual module (HTTP server), but should be fairly accurate. Desired time is then:

```
$time_microseconds = microtime(true) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'];.
```

Alternatively, Apache2 can do this as well, provided %D is added to the log entry of mod_log_config module:

```
"%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" %D".
```